# Does stabilizing reset your death saving throw counter?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw

Do any of the official rulebooks state whether death saving throws reset when you stabilize, or if you have to take a rest to reset the failure counter? My DM told me that it only resets when you rest, but I haven't seen this in any rulebooks, and I suspect this might be a house rule.

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you read the PHB section on death saving throws?

Comment: Note that it is easy to find web sites suggesting this as a house rule, such as [here](https://thinkdm.org/2018/08/11/meat-grinder-death-saves/) and [here](https://www.enworld.org/threads/death-saves-and-resting-a-rules-tweak-to-slay-elephants-and-increase-difficulty-through-all-levels.585158/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

PHB p197 under **Death Saving Throws**

> The number of both is reset to zero when you regain any hit points
> **or become stable.**